# Wordpress disqus plugin install in localhost

Tags: wordpress, disqus

I try install disqus plugin in localhost , i test my new website in local mode and when i try install disqus , the script tell me "the account no exists" , i have account in disqus website and the login and password it´s right , this happend always when i try install from admin of wordpress

For install pay me the username or email of username register and password , i try many times with the same result

I don´t know what more i can do for install in localhost

Regards and thank´s for help

Comment: Sounds like a login issue rather than an issue that can be solved here. I'd contact support instead: http://disqus.com/support/

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you already have a DISQUS account.

1. Setup your live site (even if it isn't live yet), on DISQUS' website.
2. Enable the plugin installation, including selecting the live site in the admin.
3. Then add the following code at the beginning of your `<head>` tag.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
   var disqus_developer = 1; // this would set it to developer mode
   </script>
   ```

That will enable the commenting engine to developer mode and should allow it work on localhost.